# MVVM - dagger 2 using custom factory

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I followed along with [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) guide, and went good to the point where I had to use a custom constructor for my ViewModel class (which raised a runtime crash `...UserViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`)

So, what I tried : 
  First of all I searched about it, and found out that I need a my own `Factory`implemented..

```
@Singleton
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

@Inject
public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
    this.creators = creators;
}

@NonNull
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
    if (creator == null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                creator = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (creator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
    }
    try {
        return (T) creator.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(UserViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindUserViewModel(UserViewModel userViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
}
}
```

Did that, yet I can't get my `ViewModel`instance via

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class)
```

Constructor of ViewModel class

```
@Inject
public UserViewModel(UserRepository userRepository){
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

What else can I do ? I know there are a few topics about it and I looked them up, without any success.. Am I actually missing something ?

Comment: https://github.com/Ufkoku/Dagger2.Android-Arch.Components/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ns/daggernewway/di/feed/FeedFragmentModule.kt

Comment: `yet I can't get my ViewModelinstance` could you please state the error you're getting? Your setup looks good at a glance

Comment: I did state the error. It might be a dagger configuration problem, it is not injecting objects properly I think

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that reflection failed to find zero argument constructor, I guess you have created UserViewModel with multi argument constructor and without define zero argument one. check it please..

Comment: As you could see (if read my question entierly) yes, my constructor is not a default one ! That's why I had to implement the Factory .

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the last lines of code, I'm considering the codes. everything looks great except the point is hidden. Would you please provide me with full exception stack trace?

Comment: Ended up with a solution. I had a guess that actually Dagger is not properly working and I was right. dagger wasn't injecting me the object for constructor params .. I had to do some extra configuration of dagger ( few small classes and annotations)

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan can you elaborate on what you did to make it work? I think I'm facing a similar issue as you did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create viewModel default constructor and initialize in activity or fragment like this

```
public UserViewModel(){

}
```

and initialize in activity

`UserViewModel userViewModel=new UserViewModel();
userViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class);`

I was facing same problem after that it fixed..You can use it.it will be help you.